# data.table merging and removing zeros in R

Tags: r, data.table, na

i have two large datasets and merged them on a uniqueID:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

is this the same as `df1[df2, on = "ID"]` ?

How can i replace `NAs` with `0` in a single column in `df3`? `df2` only has two columns: `value` and `ID`. By having `all.x = TRUE` a lot of `NAs` are introduced in the column `value`. I want to replace them with zero, but keep getting errors. How can this be done?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it look the same when you tried it?

Answer: No.

Since you didn't give an example, I will try.

```
library(data.table) 
df1 <- data.table(ID=2:5,a=1:4)
df2 <- data.table(ID=3:7,b=11:15)
df1
#    ID a
# 1:  2 1
# 2:  3 2
# 3:  4 3
# 4:  5 4

df2
#    ID  b
# 1:  3 11
# 2:  4 12
# 3:  5 13
# 4:  6 14
# 5:  7 15

merge(df1,df2,by="ID",all.x=TRUE)
#    ID a  b
# 1:  2 1 NA
# 2:  3 2 11
# 3:  4 3 12
# 4:  5 4 13

df1[df2,on="ID"]
#    ID  a  b
# 1:  3  2 11
# 2:  4  3 12
# 3:  5  4 13
# 4:  6 NA 14
# 5:  7 NA 15
```

They are not the same.
`df1[df2` is a right join, keeping all of `df2`. The merge has `all.x=TRUE` which keeps all of `df1`.

This is the same as your `merge`:

```
df2[df1,on="ID"]
#    ID  b a
# 1:  2 NA 1
# 2:  3 11 2
# 3:  4 12 3
# 4:  5 13 4
```

And this is the `merge` the other way:

```
merge(df1,df2,by="ID",all.y=TRUE)
#    ID  a  b
# 1:  3  2 11
# 2:  4  3 12
# 3:  5  4 13
# 4:  6 NA 14
# 5:  7 NA 15
```

And this changes `NA` to `0`:

```
df3 <- df2[df1,on="ID"][is.na(b),b:=0] 
df3
#    ID  b a
# 1:  2  0 1
# 2:  3 11 2
# 3:  4 12 3
# 4:  5 13 4
```